# How to expand my calculated field formula

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am using the following calculated field formula which works well.

> =IF(F01="YES",1,0)+IF(F02="YES",1,0)+IF(F03="YES",1,0)+IF(F05="YES",1,0)+IF(F06="YES",1,0)+IF(F07="YES",1,0)+IF(F08="YES",1,0)+IF(F09="YES",1,0)+IF(F10="YES",1,0)+IF(F11a="YES",1,0)+IF(F12="Yes",1,0)+IF(F13="Yes",1,0)+IF(F14="YES",1,0)+IF(F15="YES",1,0)+IF(F16="YES",1,0)+IF(F17="No",1,0)+IF(F18="No",1,0)+IF(F20="No",1,0)+IF(F21="Yes",1,0)+IF(F22="YES",1,0)

What I need to ad is in some cases the question needs to meet two criteria...

Example

Right now if `F01=Yes` then I tally but I need to now tally only if `FO1=Yes and TCV is > 25000000`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=IF(  AND( F01="YES", TCV > 25000000 ), 1, 0 ) + ...
```

If that additional test applies to all of the "F" values then:

```
=IF( TCV > 25000000,   
IF(F01="YES",1,0)+IF(F02="YES",1,0)+IF(F03="YES",1,0)+IF(F05="YES",1,0)
+IF(F06="YES",1,0)+IF(F07="YES",1,0)+IF(F08="YES",1,0)+IF(F09="YES",1,0)
+IF(F10="YES",1,0)+IF(F11a="YES",1,0)+IF(F12="Yes",1,0)+IF(F13="Yes",1,0)
+IF(F14="YES",1,0)+IF(F15="YES",1,0)+IF(F16="YES",1,0)+IF(F17="No",1,0)
+IF(F18="No",1,0)+IF(F20="No",1,0)+IF(F21="Yes",1,0)+IF(F22="YES",1,0)
, 0)
```

Which version SharePoint are you using? 2007 and 2010 have a maximum formula length of 1024 characters.